# Retrieve Database values and show them on form using SQLDataReader

Tags: c#, sql, database, listbox, sqldatareader

I am trying to retrieve data from a Database and show them on a form; but my code isn't working... I've got no errors, and logically it seems to work (to me) so I cannot figure out where I have gone wrong. That's where I need your help!

```
private void tableListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string constring = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\IncomerDefault.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
    string Query = "SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE Default_Name = '" + tableListBox.SelectedValue + "'";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, con);
    SqlDataReader Reader;
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (Reader.Read())
        {
                textBox1.Text = Reader.GetValue(2).ToString();
                comboBox1.Text = Reader.GetValue(3).ToString();
                comboBox3.Text = Reader.GetValue(4).ToString();
                textBox2.Text = Reader.GetValue(6).ToString();
                comboBox2.Text = Reader.GetValue(7).ToString();
                comboBox4.Text = Reader.GetValue(8).ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

The 'tableListBox' is populated with all the values in column 'Default_Name'. I want it so that when the 'Default_Name' is selected from the list box it shows the values, in textboxes and comboboxes, that correspond with that row in the Database.

Any and all help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: can i assume the list box has predetermined values in it, or is built from another method?

Comment: Hi Takarii, the list box is populated from the same database, under a 'Fill' method

Comment: my current thinking is simply that your query isn't returning any results. Id recommend checking that your sql query itself is actually what you are expecting - it is possible the listbox isnt actually supplying the value you are hoping.

Comment: Hi Takarii, I put in a random label and tried to make the label.Text equal the listBox selection and it didn't change, so I think you are correct; the listbox isn't supplying the value I was hoping for.

Comment: use the `ListBox.ValueMember = "Default_Name"` property to allow value assignment - this way the name in the listbox will become the value of the item selected

Comment: previous comment assumes thats the column header used to fill the listbox ^^. If this fixes your problem, ill write it up as an answer so you can flag it

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either. I used a random label again to see if 'tableListBox.Valuemember' was supplying a value and it wasn't doing anything.

Comment: Are you committed to a listbox, or would a combobox work too?

Comment: I would prefer to use a Listbox

Comment: Can you show us your listbox assignment code?

Comment: I have figured out where I went wrong. First I was using the void 'SelectedItemChanged', that was the first problem because it wasn't seeing an index change, so I have changed it to 'SelectedValueChanged'.

Comment: Awesome. Glad I could help point you in the rough direction.

Comment: I seem to only be able to show the Row index of the selected value, so my question now, is how do I edit the Query string to have the 'Default_Name' equal the row index?

Comment: Your help was very much appreciated Takarii

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to start by changing your design a bit and suggest that perhaps you look at using a datatable and then just retrieving the rows from the datatable.

```
private void tableListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    private DataTable dataTable;
    string constring = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\IncomerDefault.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
    string Query = "SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE Default_Name = '" + tableListBox.SelectedValue + "'";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, con);
    try
    {
         con.Open();

         SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
         da.Fill(dataTable);

         foreach(DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
         {
              textBox1.Text = row[2].ToString();
              comboBox1.Text = row[3].ToString();
              comboBox3.Text = row[4].ToString();
              textBox2.Text = row[6].ToString();
              comboBox2.Text = row[7].ToString();
              comboBox4.Text = row[8].ToString();
        }
        da.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    con.Close();
 }
```

I generally find that DataTables are more reliable than looping through the actual reader. Ofcourse this assumes that there is data being returned. Also try changing your select statement to this

```
string Query = "SELECT * FROM [Table]"
```

If that works, then the problem could be

1. There is no default name of the specified value or
2. tableListBox.SelectedValue is not returning any value, in which case, have a look at your listbox selected value

Comment: Datatables will do the job, but its a heavy solution when only returning a single row of data.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Takarii for helping. I figured out who to make it work.

```
private void tableListBox_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string constring = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\IncomerDefault.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
    string Query = "SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE ID = '" + tableListBox.SelectedIndex.ToString() + "'";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, con);
    SqlDataReader Reader;
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (Reader.Read())
        {
            textBox1.Text = Reader.GetValue(2).ToString();
            comboBox1.Text = Reader.GetValue(3).ToString();
            comboBox3.Text = Reader.GetValue(4).ToString();
            textBox2.Text = Reader.GetValue(6).ToString();
            comboBox2.Text = Reader.GetValue(7).ToString();
            comboBox4.Text = Reader.GetValue(8).ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

First I changed the void to 'SelectedValueChanged' and then I changed the 'WHERE' in the connection Query to the Row Index associated with the selected Value.

Thanks for everyone's help!